# Partial expansion of code in scheme

Tags: scheme, eval, racket

I have a need to partially expand scheme code without completely evaluated. I'd like a function that takes something like this:

```
'(let [(my-number 8)
       (my-function (lambda args 'value))]
  (cond
    ((> my-number 10) (my-function 'x 'y 'z))
    ((= my-number 10) (my-function 'a 'b 'c))
    (else my-number)))
```

and turns it into this:

```
'(cond
  ((> 8 10) 'value)
  ((= 8 10) 'value)
  (else 8))
```

In other words, I want something that expands definitions, lets, letrecs, etc. without doing any dangerous evaluation. I plan to do some static analysis on some varied scheme code, and it would be nice if all the code is in a relatively normalized form. I'd like to do as much expansion as possible without risking any I/O.

What this entails is basically writing a scheme evaluator. I'd rather not. Is there any scheme functions that help me do this out of the box?

I should clarify that I don't have control over the input. I'm given the input as-is and I've got to analyze it; I'd prefer to normalize it before doing my analysis. That's what I'm trying to achieve here. It's not possible for me to re-write the input by hand to make life easier.

I'm using racket, but unfortunately my code has to run with `#lang scheme`.

Comment: What's "dangerous evaluation" for you?

Comment: Mutating the global scope, sleeping, forking, or otherwise doing I/O.

I'd like to expand user-made definitions in the user's code-block, including lambdas, defines, lets, and anything in the define/let family. I'd like macros to be expanded too, if possible. Ideally, I'd like to do all syntactic expansion I can without modifying state or doing I/O, but a whitelist might suffice. Do you know of a comprehensive list of the define-like and let-like functions?

Comment: If you can do 'static analysis', then you can do 'partial evaluation'...

Comment: I certainly can. But I'd rather spend my time on the more interesting aspects of the problem at hand.

Comment: Not sure if it would help with part of what you want, but Racket has a sandboxed evaluator: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html

Comment: Related question using `#lang racket`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78190394/21891079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [`expand`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Expanding_Top-Level_Forms.html?q=expand#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._expand%29%29) is what you're looking for? It will *not* produce an output as the one in the question, but it will:

> Expand all non-primitive syntax in top-level-form, and return a syntax object for the expanded form that contains only core forms, matching the grammar specified by Fully Expanded Programs

Here's an usage example:

```
(define src
  '(let [(my-number 8)
         (my-function (lambda args 'value))]
     (cond
       ((> my-number 10) (my-function 'x 'y 'z))
       ((= my-number 10) (my-function 'a 'b 'c))
       (else my-number))))

(syntax->datum
 (parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
   (expand (datum->syntax #f src))))
```

With this output:

```
(let-values (((my-number) '8) ((my-function) (lambda args 'value)))
  (if (#%app > my-number '10)
    (let-values () (#%app my-function 'x 'y 'z))
    (if (#%app = my-number '10)
      (let-values () (#%app my-function 'a 'b 'c))
      (let-values () my-number))))
```

Notice that if we remove the `syntax->datum` conversion, the value returned by `expand` will be a [syntax object](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html?q=expand#%28part._stxobj-model%29), which could be more useful for performing the analysis you have in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure you quite understand the question. I want a function that takes, as input, the first code sample, and returns, as output, the second. I do not generate the code samples: I am going to be reading a  bunch of existing code, which I would like to normalize before statically analyzing.

Comment: I still don't think you understand. I don't get to write the input. I have no control over the input. I would like to do certain expansions (of lambdas and anything in the define* and let* families) and no more -- is there some sort of restricted eval that I could use?

Comment: expand is a start -- it certainly makes the partial evaluation easier, by narrowing down the cases I'd have to handle if I end up writing the partial evaluator myself.

Comment: Yes, it seems like it. And see the last paragraph in my answer, that could be useful, too. But I don't think you'll find something closer to the expected output in the question, and the "no dangerous evaluation" part is going to be hard to find