# How to programmatically expand the let* family of functions in racket

Tags: scheme, racket, let

#### Context

*This question is tangentially related to a homework assignment, but I am not looking to have someone do my work for me.*

I have an assignment where we are discouraged from overuse of [`let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%29%29), [`let*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%2A%29%29), and similar functions to encourage us to "think functionally".

I also understand that expressions using `let` can be expanded to only use `lambda` in the following manner.

```lisp
#lang racket

; using let
(let ([x 1] [y 2]) (+ x y))

; with lambda
((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 1 2)
```

Looking at this caused me to ask the following question.

#### The Question

Is there some way to accomplish this expansion programmatically? The only part that should be modified are those using `let`, `let*`, and so on.

```lisp
> (expand-let '(let ([x 1] [y 2]) (+ x y)))
'((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 1 2)
```

It would be cool if this could apply to all ["local binding" Racket functions](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#(part._let)): `let`, `let*`, `letrec`, `let-values`, `let*-values`, `letrec-values`, and so on.

*As pointed out in the comments, this doesn't really serve any practical purpose for my assignment, but I am still looking into it as a personal project as I am new to Racket. Any advice is appreciated*.

#### What I've tried

- [Sylwester's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39239764/21891079) to [Not able to use let in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39239764/21891079) discusses the expansion of `let` and `letrec` but does so by hand.
- [Alex Knauth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640948/21891079) to [When to use define and when to use let in racket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53637079/21891079) includes a helpful discussion of the scopes of `let`, `let*`, and `letrec`.
- [Partial expansion of code in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17223785/21891079) is honestly pretty close to what I am looking for, but I will point out a few differences

  - I don't need to evaluate the code, simply expand what I consider to be "syntactic sugar" in this context
  - The question requires `#lang scheme`, but this question uses `#lang racket`
  - A comment refers the OP to [Racket's Sandboxed Evaluation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html) but I am not sure that is what I am looking for (advice is appreciated). It seems like this is used to provide some control over how code is evaluated, but what I am looking for is not control over evaluation. It is about expanding functions used for local bindings when they can be rewritten using `lambda`.
  - The answer links to [`expand`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Expanding_Top-Level_Forms.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._expand%29%29) and this seems to get me closer (maybe?) but I am struggling to find a way forward.

    ```lisp
    > (syntax-e (expand '(let ([x 1] [y 2]) (+ x y))))
    '(#<syntax:/Applications/Racket v8.11.1/collects/racket/private/qq-and-or.rkt:193:51 let-values>
      #<syntax (((x) (quote 1)) ((y) (quote 2)))>
      #<syntax:/Applications/Racket v8.11.1/collects/racket/private/kw.rkt:1263:25 (#%app + x y)>)
    ```

##### Coding it myself (not a complete solution)

I attempted my own solution as a beginner and got stuck. Any advice is appreciated.

```lisp
(define (expand-let atomized-expr)
  (expand-let-helper (syntax->datum (expand atomized-expr)) (lambda (result) result)))
(define (expand-let-helper parse-tree return)
  (define (expand-let-bindings bindings)
    (map (lambda (binding) (list (caar binding) (expand-let (cadr binding)))) bindings))
  (cond
    [(null? parse-tree) (return '())]
    [(not (pair? parse-tree)) (return parse-tree)]
    [(eq? (car parse-tree) '#%app)
     (expand-let-helper (cdr parse-tree) (lambda (result) (return result)))]
    [(eq? (car parse-tree) '#%top) (return (cdr parse-tree))]
    [(eq? (car parse-tree) 'let-values)
     (let* ([bindings (cadr parse-tree)]
            [body (cddr parse-tree)]
            [expanded-bindings (expand-let-bindings bindings)]
            [vars (map car expanded-bindings)]
            [vals (map cadr expanded-bindings)])
       (expand-let-helper body
                          (lambda (result)
                            (return `((lambda (,@vars) ,@result) ,@vals)))))]
    [else
     (expand-let-helper (cdr parse-tree)
                        (lambda (cdr-result)
                          (expand-let-helper (car parse-tree)
                                             (lambda (car-result)
                                               (return (cons car-result cdr-result))))))]))
```

See results here:

```lisp
; successful case
> ((lambda (x y) (let ((a (+ x y)) (b (- x y))) (* a b))) 1 2)
-3
> (expand-let '((lambda (x y) (let ((a (+ x y)) (b (- x y))) (* a b))) 1 2))
'((lambda (x y) ((lambda (a b) (* a b)) (+ x y) (- x y))) '1 '2)
> (eval (expand-let '((lambda (x y) (let ((a (+ x y)) (b (- x y))) (* a b))) 1 2)))
-3

; failing cases (pointed out in comments)
> (expand-let '(let ([n (random -10 10)]) (cond [(positive? n) 1] [(negative? n) -1] [else 0])))
'((lambda (n) (if (positive? n) '1 (if (negative? n) '-1 '0)))
  (random '-10 '10))
```

Comment: You could implement `expand-let` as a recursive case analysis. Pattern matching support like `racket/match` or `syntax-rules` would be helpful. One problem you will run into is that your function will need to understand all syntactic forms, not just binding forms, in order to do this properly. And if you want to transform an entire file and have it still be readable, you'll likely run into trouble preserving whitespace, comments, and () vs. []. (The transformed expression in your example should be `((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 1 2)`, by the way.)

Comment: @PeterWinton Thank you for the pointers and for catching that mistake! I've edited the question to fix that.

Comment: You need a code walker to do this.  Anything that does this programmatically is also going to remove any comments from your code of course.  Also  in what sense is `((lambda (x) ...) ...)`  'more functional' than `(let ((x ...)) ...)`?  It certainly is harder to read.

Comment: I have two complaints, one for you and one for whoever set you this task. (1) There is nothing "non-functional" about `let`, it's just a good way to name intermediate steps. (2) If you're supposed to avoid thinking in terms of `let`, then writing `let`s but automatically translating them into lambda applications will not be much good. You won't learn whatever alternate method of thinking was intended, and it will be very transparent to whoever is scoring this assignment that you did that. Nobody writes `((lambda (...) ...) ...)` in real life, and it sticks out like a sore thumb.

Comment: @ignisvolens thank you for the advice. I agree that the use of `let` is no "less functional" than the use of `lambda`. This was a programming challenge inspired by a requirement in an assignment that I'm am investigating for personal purposes (at this point). I will try to make that clearer in the question.

Thank you for the advice about using a code walker as well. This is new to me and I can't seem to find resources online very easily... do you have any advice on where to start?

Comment: @amalloy (1) Agreed. I am approaching this as a personal project (for fun) with that understanding. (2) Thank you for the advice on that front. What we were supposed to use instead were good abstractions for repeated intermediate processing steps and I use `let` when I write the code to identify when I repeat certain steps. I will not be using this on my assignment after seeing how it works on smaller examples, but I'm still trying to see what I can do with this as a learning device.

Comment: @JoshuaShew: no, I don't know of a general-purpose code-walker for Scheme.  I think the problem is not simple to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that not even Racket's syntax expander could do this properly without significant effort. When the transformer encounters `(let ...)`, it needs to determine if `let` is a macro or a variable bound by an enclosing expression.

```
> ((lambda (let) (+ let 1)) 1)
2
```

So the transformer needs to track the local environment and know details about the `#lang` in use and any modules required at the top level.

Assuming a particular instance of `(let ([id value-expr] ...) body ...)` is determined to be a macro, the transformer must transform it into a lambda expression and application and also recursively transform sub-expressions, but *only* the value expressions and body expressions. It would be an error to treat `[id value-expr]` as a procedure application, for example. In other words, the transformer must understand the semantics of the macros it encounters.

That goes for custom macros, too. Suppose you encounter the following code.

```
(define-syntax my-macro some-transformer-procedure)
(my-macro (let ((a 1)) (b 2)))
```

You can at least know that `(my-macro (let ((a 1)) (b 2)))` is a macro invocation. The let-expression *looks* like a normal `let`, but you don't know what the macro will transform it into, and thus cannot expand it properly, without understanding the macro's semantics. And the semantics are encapsulated in `some-transformer-procedure`, which is a black box, and the macro's documentation, which is not machine-readable.

If you devised a method to specify the semantics of every macro and could ensure that all custom macros provided a complete and correct spec readable by the transformer, then you might have a chance. The fact that macros can define other macros ad infinitum greatly increases the complexity of this hypothetical system.

Somewhat ironically, these challenges highlight one of the benefits of Racket's macro system. The compiler needs to analyze expressions in a manner similar to what you're attempting. To make its work easier, it uses macros to distill complex constructs down to a handful of core expressions like `lambda` and `if` that it can subsequently manipulate according to a set of rules that are guaranteed to preserve correctness. The simpler the expressions are, the simpler and more widely-applicable the rules can be, allowing for powerful optimizations.

Here's one example using ChezScheme:

```
> (print-gensym #f)
> (expand/optimize
   '(lambda (x)
      (let* ([f1 (lambda (lt) (lambda (a b) (lt a b)))]
             [f2 (lambda () (f1 <))])
        ((f2) (+ 1 2) x))))
(lambda (x) (#2%< 3 x))
```

As you can see, it was able to simplify the expression quite a bit. (`#2%<` is a particular implementation of the `<` procedure that the compiler decided was appropriate.)